# How to $watch type="files" inside the cell of Datatable - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a Upload button inside a cell of Datatable, I have a clickHandler for a click event. The Upload button is called Window Explorer and I can select files to upload. In order to upload files to the server, I am using $watch to check for changes on the model "files", if there is any change, it will trigger the upload function. This function will upload files to the server. But It seems like $watch never sees what is going on inside the datatable. Here is my codes:

I am using angular-file-upload, and it seems to work on other part of the websites where I am not using an upload button inside the datatable.

When I run the code, it pops up the alert("test") and window to select files, but it never calls the server. No network call can be seen on the browser.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my codes?
Thank you.

View:

```
 <td><a class="btn btn-primary" ng-file-select ng-model="files" ng-multiple="true">Upload documents</a> </td>
```

cell click event:

```
$('td:eq(11)', nRow).bind('click', function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.clickHandler(aData);

        });

    });
```

$watch controller:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function (data) {
    //alert('upload document');        
    var appList = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem(Constant.ApplicationKey));
    var id = data[0];

    angular.forEach(appList, function (v) {
        if (v.PersonID == id) {
            $scope.selectedUserName = v.FirstName + " " + v.LastName;
            return;
        }
    })
    $scope.$watch('files', function () {
        $scope.upload($scope.files);
        alert("test");
    })

}
```

Upload function

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            $upload.upload({
                url: Constant.BaseUrl + 'api/User/UploadFile',
                params: { username: $scope.selectedUserName, Role: 'Student' },
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                            evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' +
                            JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new watcher everytime you click on the button. `$scope.$watch(...)` will register a new watcher everytime and you will have probably have problems.

Couldn't you just upload the files once the user clicks? Also, try not using a jQuery event listener but an angular `ng-click` instead soyou don't have model/view inconsistencies:

HTML:

```
<td ng-click="onClick(files)"> ... </td>
```

controller:

```
$scope.onClick = function (files) {
  console.log('Handler clicked with files:', files);
  if (files) {
    console.log('Uploading files');
    $scope.upload(files);
  }
};
```

Actually, you want to run the upload when you click where exactly? I guess you need to wait until the user has selected the file modal and selected the files he wants to upload.

Comment: ng-file-select allows users to select the files that they want to upload. I dont think i need modal in this case.

Comment: @user1874435 nah by modal I mean the regular popup in your OS from which you can select the files. I guess you wwant to upload them only once the user has selected them on this "popup"

Comment: The current ng-file-select will popup a window for users to select the files. So it is done by the directive. Now i need to check for any change on that directive and do the upload. Is that making sense?

Comment: I know all this, I also use this directive (starting today actually). I'm just wondering where your `clickHandler` is hooked: if that click event happens after the user has selected the files, you don't need to `$watch` anything, just upload what's on your `ng-model`